# How to get last order number in WooCommerce and insert next?

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, function, woocommerce

I am developing an offline product for retail. This will be sold by a distributor NOT through my website. I have a sequential order reference system based on WooCommerce such as 152, 153 etc.

I want to create an SQL query to find the last order number (reference ID) from WP-database and create a function to insert my offline order into the WP database using the next reference number in sequence.

Hope this makes sense.

Any suggestions how I can achieve this or is there an easier way to link my offline orders in?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
  SELECT * FROM `wp_woocommerce_order_items` 
  ORDER BY `wp_woocommerce_order_items`.`order_item_id` DESC 
  LIMIT 1
```